# How to use InputMethodService in wifi p2p service discovery?

Tags: android, wifi-direct, android-input-method, wifip2p

I am new to android, please tell me if inputMethodService can work with wifi p2p service discovery? I want one phone to act as a keyboard for another phone. Please tell me if it is possible and which resources to refer in order to begin with it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is not worry about the input-method in the first device, but create an application where you input text as normal from what ever you are using for input on the android device and then make that application responsible to transfer the acquired text to another device in which you want to input, in real time.

Given the restrictions on the IME in android, the other device should have the modified input-method that receives the data and enters for you in turn.

You have to be very careful for this kind of data transfer because the IME in android is essentially capable of monitoring anything the user enters, so the data transfer should be really really secure.