# Making a keyboard app on one android phone to act as a Bluetooth keyboard for another android phone

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method

I have developed a keyboard for android but I want to add a functionality through which it can act as a remote keyboard device for another android phone, is this possible? Can someone post some information regarding the same?

Comment: Question is too broad. Yes you can connect devices over Bluetooth, yes you could send keystrokes. Can the other device receive them? Unknown... How would you determine where you're typing? How would it be any different than a regular Bluetooth keyboard?

Comment: I want it to act as a regular Bluetooth keyboard just that it is an app sitting on an android device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40338666/how-to-use-inputmethodservice-in-wifi-p2p-service-discovery?answertab=active#tab-top). I am pasting the same text as i answered there.

I think what you need to do is not worry about the input-method in the first device, but create an application where you input text as normal from what ever you are using for input on the android device and then make that application responsible to transfer the acquired text to another device in which you want to input, in real time.

Given the restrictions on the IME in android, the other device should have the modified input-method that receives the data and enters for you in turn.

You have to be very careful for this kind of data transfer because the IME in android is essentially capable of monitoring anything the user enters, so the data transfer should be really really secure.